# Increase number by 1 if the row data is same

Tags: sql

I have a table where there are many rows.
The format of the table is somewhere like this

```
     col1|col2
     ---------
     001 |01|
     001 |01|
     001 |01|
     001 |01|
     001 |02|
     001 |02|
     001 |02|
     001 |02|
     001 |03|
     001 |03|
     001 |03|
     002 |01|
     002 |01|
     002 |01|
     002 |01|
```

I want to add a new column in the table where the values of col1 and col2 are checked and new value is inserted in col3

```
col1|col2|col3
---------------
 001 |01 |1
 001 |01 |2
 001 |01 |3
 001 |01 |4
 001 |02 |1
 001 |02 |2
 001 |02 |3
 001 |02 |4
 001 |03 |1
 001 |03 |2
 001 |03 |3
 002 |01 |1
 002 |01 |2
 002 |01 |3
 002 |01 |4
```

Comment: what is your dbms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `row_number()` wich support most dbms

```
select *, row_number() over(partition by col1,col2 order by col2) as col3
 from table_name
```